# Change text color in nav bar "Bootstrap"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a new user to bootstrap and want to change the color of the items in the navigation bar.

Have created my own css file called Site.CSS, but also have the bootstrap.css file. Right now the text color of the heading "Home, booking, contact, login and register" is grey. When you hoover over it, it turns white.

I want it to be white as standard and change it to grey as you hoover over it with the mouse.

**Some code i have of the master page:**

```
<form id="form" runat="server">
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/default.aspx">M-Hotels</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Booking.aspx">Booking</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Registration.aspx">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Login.aspx">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a runat="server" href="~/User.aspx" title="Manage your account">Hello,!</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a runat="server" href="~/default.aspx" title="Log out"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - M-Hotels A/S</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</form>
```

Can any tell me, if i am supposed to change something in the bootstrap file or if i must add something to the Site.css file.

Comment: On each ul.nav, you could add an ID, and override the Bootstrap CSS using a more specific rule. However, if you have configured the CSS correctly, and loaded the Site.css file AFTER the bootstrap css file, then it should work fine! Do you have an example of your CSS for the nav bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this code in your Site.css file

```
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
   color: #fff;
 }

.nav.navbar-nav a:hover {
 color: grey;
}
```

Comment: works for me too and this is the only answer in all questions in same domain that is easy to understand and successful.

Comment: Works for me, except on the `brand` div.

Answer (score 0):

You should add something to your site.css 
What probably happens is that bootstrap styles are overwriting what you write. In that case you need to increase specificity

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.nav.navbar-nav li a {
     color: #fff !important; 
 }
 .nav .navbar-nav li a:hover { 
     color: grey !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but this is what worked for me:

```
a {
color: #536872;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

`